# How to Connect to Microsoft Dynamics Navision (NAV) Web Services Endpoints Using SOAP?

Tags: soap, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I can successfully connect to the main Page for the web service which lists all of the end point URLs;

```
http://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/WS/<CompanyName>/Page/<ServiceName>
```

But no matter what combination of URLs / parameters I have tested, I cannot seem to actually connect to any of the end point URLs, they come back with an error every time saying that the page does not exist.

What am I missing? The documentation on this is abysmal from Microsoft.

Comment: AFAIK soap uses http `POST` method so you can’t get any response from it by using only URL (which is a `GET` method). The page you are seeing is WSDL - definition of soap interface.

Comment: @MakSim Correct. Yes, I should have worded the question better. I am using a SOAP client to run the request as POST rather than GET. The WSDL that I'm seeing isn't actually that helpful. For example, one of the endpoints listed is 'Read', now where abouts should this go? Is that appended to the end of the URL as /read or /read/ or something else? Or should this be included within the 'body' of the soap request, and if so, what should that format look like?

Comment: Feed this wsdl to soapUI. It will do the job.